# Wordpress wp-content plugins not admin add_menu_page

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get Wordpress add_menu_page with an external PHP file for the admin page (as part of a so far failing learning excerise).

I have the following folder structure

```
/plugin-name
     plugin-name.php
     uninstall.php  
     /languages
     /includes
          /views
     /admin
          /js
          /css
          /images
     /public
          /js
          /css
          /images
```

and as by the code below, am trying to make sure that the php is loaded from the wp-content plugins directory, but all my attempts so far to make sure I always reference the wp-content/plugins folder have failed and I always end up in the wp-admin directory : -

```
//define('MYPLUGINS_BASEPATH', plugins_url(__FILE__));

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'MYPLUGINS_datatest_options_page' );
function MYPLUGINS_datatest_options_page() {

    //$test99 = basename("https://MYSERVER.com/wp-content/includes/views/admin/");
    $test99 = basename("https://MYSERVER.com/wp-content/");

    add_menu_page(
        'MYPLUG Data Test TITLE text',  // Title of page
        'MYPLUG Data Test LINK text',   // Menu link text
        'manage_options',
        $test99, //'includes/views/admin/datatest-admin-page.php',
        null,
        null, //plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'images/icon_wporg.png',
        80 //20
    );
}
```

What is the best and most reliable way to always have the wp-content/plugins folder referenced?

My reference above to $test99 I know should it not be an actual path to the file as opposed to a url, as if i try https://MYSERVER.com/wp-content/includes/views/admin/datatest-admin-page.php in the browser it says 404.

I have tried the reference out there and looked at other plug ins and I can't work out how to get the thing to not look in wp-admin.

I read using the wp_plugindir is not a good idea, and plugins_url always leaves me in wp-admin too.

Juageer

Comment: The fourth argument to `add_menu_page` is the menu slug, not an URL. You provide the content of the page in the `$function` argument. Check https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/

Comment: I am trying to make this work https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/administration-menus/top-level-menus/#using-a-php-file-for-html

Comment: But I always stuck in wp-admin and my plugin code is is wp-content/plugins